# Swift 1.2 -> Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I'm coding an app for my Kids. I have background in Java but havn't professionally coded in a decade. I don't thoroughly understand how the following line works but it worked in Swift 1.2:

```
leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({ (scores:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
```

I need help translating this into working Swift 2.0 code. Could someone please post a translation of working Swift 2.0 code for the following method:

```
func getHighscores(leaderboardID: String) {

    let leaderboardRequest = GKLeaderboard() as GKLeaderboard!
    leaderboardRequest.identifier = leaderboardID

    if leaderboardRequest != nil
    {
        leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({ (scores:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                //println("error in alltimeHighscoreForLevel")
                print(error.description)
                self.updateLocalHighscore()
            }
            else
            {
                if(leaderboardRequest != nil){
                    if(leaderboardRequest.scores != nil ) {
                        if(leaderboardRequest.scores!.count > 0){
                            self.updateHighestForLevel(leaderboardRequest)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to read the Swift 2 documentation, especially where it discusses the new throw / catch syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({ (scores, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
         // from here on your code should work
```

I think the definition of `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` changed from the old code.

Answer (score 1):

Two common ways to solve this:

- Comment out the line / method which causes the error and start to retype it. The code completion will reveal the proper signature of the method. Then copy and paste the relevant code from the old line / method to the new one and resolve potential errors / warnings.
- Press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> and type (or copy&paste) the beginning of the method for example `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` into the search field. This will take you to the documentation and you can see the whole declaration including the discussion.